# JQuery CSS Transform Scale Property not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

And I have a div with `class="sc-bar"` which act as a scroll bar of the "container". Now I want to transform "sc-bar" through JQuery CSS property,

```
$('.sc-bar').css('transform','scaleY(0.5)');
```

But not working, I also tried with all prefixes like webkit, moz.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/n7s1hvkv/. Have you included jQuery.js properly, and run your code in a document.ready handler? Also make sure you're testing in a browser which supports CSS transforms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've actually tested below and seems to be working?

```
$('.sc-bar').css('transform','scaleY(0.5)');
```

Is the line enclose on $(document).ready() or made sure that jQuery is loaded before using this like below?

```
// A $( document ).ready() block.
$(document).ready(function() {
    // your code here...
    $('.sc-bar').css('transform','scaleY(0.5)');
});
```